# Why appearance of RecyleView button is messed up?

Tags: python, kivy

I've encountered a bizarre problem. I've got 3 RecycleViews in a GridLayout and they all share
the same problem. The button area appears to cover only first 100px of the text.

[image]

How can this be fixed ?

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        RV:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                pos: 10, 4
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        RV:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                pos: 10, 4
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        RV:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                pos: 10, 4
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'five'
        Label:
            text: 'six'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding `default_size_hint` and `default_size` attributes.
I had no clue that RecycleView had those.

```
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        RV:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: 100, 30
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```